# Midpoint Formula returning weird output in JS

Tags: javascript, math

so i have the following code:

```
function domidpoint() {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("x1").value;
    var y1 = document.getElementById("y1").value;
    var x2 = document.getElementById("x2").value;
    var y2 = document.getElementById("y2").value;
    var midpointx, midpointy;
    if(x1, y1, x2, y2 != '') {
        midpointx = (x1 + x2) / 2;
        midpointy = (y1 + y2) / 2;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = midpointx.toString() + "," + midpointy.toString();
    }
}
```

but when I run it with the values, (-6,8),(6,-7) which should return a midpoint of (0,0.5) I get the output -33,NaN. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is? I am fairly new to javascript so if I am doing something stupid feel free to tell me so.

Comment: What is `x1, y1, x2, y2 != ''` supposed to be testing?

Comment: I don't know any programming language where `if(x1, y1, x2, y2 != '')` is valid. In JavaScript, that code is equal to `if(y2 != '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two problems with your code the first is that you have a syntax error in `if(x1, y1, x2, y2 != '')` you should do each check alone `x1 != ''` and separate them with `AND` operator `&&` see  the code below

the second problem is that `document.getElementById("x1").value` return a `string` not `number` so you need to convert it to number before using it
to avoid unwanted behaviours

```
function domidpoint() {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("x1").value;
    var y1 = document.getElementById("y1").value;
    var x2 = document.getElementById("x2").value;
    var y2 = document.getElementById("y2").value;
    var midpointx, midpointy;
    if (x1 != "" && x2 != "" && y1 != "" && y2 != "") {
        midpointx = (Number(x1) + Number(x2)) / 2;
        midpointy = (Number(y1) + Number(y2)) / 2;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = midpointx.toString() + "," + midpointy.toString();
    }
}
```

at last it seems that you are new to javascript so here are two great resorses to help you understand javascript basics

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6NZfCO5SIk --- (video)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics --  (article)

Answer (score 0):

`value` returns a string; using `+` means addition for numbers, but *concatenation* for strings.  (See what `x1+x2` and `y1+y2` are to see the difference.)

Answer (score 0):

When you read something from DOM, It returns a string, and when you try to perform any action on it. Something like this happens:

```
const midPointX = '-66'/2;
const midPointY = '8-7'/2;
```

The first point is still valid that's why you are getting -33. If you change the order to(x2 + x1) you will get NaN.

`'8-7'` is not a valid number that is why you are getting NaN.

**NOTE:** You perform arithmetic operation(-,*,/,%) on a string, **except addition(+)**.

```
'1' + '2'; // '12'
'1' - '2'; // -1
```

To Solve this you have to convert a string to a number.

```js
const x1 = '-6', y1 = '8', x2 = '6', y2 = '-7';
const midPointX = (+x1 + +x2) / 2;
const midPointY = (+y1 + +y2) / 2;

console.log(midPointX, midPointY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all values ​​are converted to number type before calculating

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).